# sorting list of files based upon the first numeric value

Tags: shell, unix, sorting, sed, awk

I am new to Unix. I need some help in sorting file names. I have a list of files as below:

```
FILE10_11_9_1_C.sql 
FILE11_11_9_1_P.sql 
LE12_11-9-1-P.sql 
FILE13_11-9-1-P.sql 
FILE14_11_9_1_P.sql 
E15_11_9_1_P.sql 
FILE16_11_9_1_P.sql 
FILE17_11_9_1_U.sql 
FILE17_11_9_1_U.sql 
FILE5_11_9_1_A.sql 
FILE7_PKG_C.sql 
FILE8_PKG_CV.sql 
Fi1_11_9_1_E.sql 
File2_11_9_1_E.sql 
File3_11_9_1_C.sql 
FILE4_11_9_1_P.sql
```

I want to sort it numerically till first underscore is encountered(number can be at anyposition and not eaxct at 5th position). For ex- as below:

```
File1_11_9_1 
File2_11_9_1 
. 
. 
. 
File8_Pkg 
File10_11_9_1
```

I am trying with `ls -1|sort -t"_" -k1,4n`
but this does'nt seem to work.

Comment: I think it works. Anyway, it puts File10 before File1, File2...

Comment: This does exactly what you need:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/02/sorting-files-based-upon-numeric-value.html

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sort -k1.5n file
File1_11_9_1_E.sql
File2_11_9_1_E.sql
File3_11_9_1_C.sql
FILE4_11_9_1_P.sql
FILE5_11_9_1_A.sql
FILE7_PKG_C.sql
FILE8_PKG_CV.sql
FILE10_11_9_1_C.sql
FILE11_11_9_1_P.sql
FILE12_11-9-1-P.sql
FILE13_11-9-1-P.sql
FILE14_11_9_1_P.sql
FILE15_11_9_1_P.sql
FILE16_11_9_1_P.sql
FILE17_11_9_1_U.sql
FILE17_11_9_1_U.sql
```

Comment: it just starts the sorting numerically (n) at the 5th character of the first field (-k1.5) so it skips over the word "file" then sorts numerically.

Comment: I found the explanation in `info sort` this feature (character and field) is not described in `man sort`. Certainly makes a lot of task easier! Already got my +1.

Comment: The . notation is described in the man file, albeit tersely and following the list of options: "POS is F[.C][OPTS], where F is the field number and C the character position in the field; both are origin 1." Given that POS is only used with the `-k` option, I don't know why they omit that from `-k`'s description to state later.

Comment: +1 @sudo_O in my man-page, I can see it at line nr 80 . you can man sort, then type `80G`

Comment: @Kent so it is, I never noticed it as it's not under the option description of `-k`. Must read complete man page in future!

Answer (score 0):

well I am a bit lazy to remember sort fancy options.

just combine linux power text handlers to achieve it. There must be more elegant way to do that. but this is working without too much thinking

```
your ls...|awk -F'[Ee_]' '{print $2" "$0}'|sort -n|sed -r 's/[0-9]+ //'
```

**EDIT**

add a pure awk one-liner:

```
ls...|awk -F'[Ee_]' '{a[NR]=$2;b[$2]=$0;}END{n=asort(a);for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print b[a[i]]}'
```

works like:

```
kent$  echo "FILE10_11_9_1_C.sql 
FILE11_11_9_1_P.sql 
FILE12_11-9-1-P.sql 
FILE13_11-9-1-P.sql 
FILE14_11_9_1_P.sql 
FILE15_11_9_1_P.sql 
FILE16_11_9_1_P.sql 
FILE17_11_9_1_U.sql 
FILE17_11_9_1_U.sql 
FILE5_11_9_1_A.sql 
FILE7_PKG_C.sql 
FILE8_PKG_CV.sql 
File1_11_9_1_E.sql 
File2_11_9_1_E.sql 
File3_11_9_1_C.sql 
FILE4_11_9_1_P.sql"|awk -F'[Ee_]' '{print $2" "$0}'|sort -n|sed -r 's/[0-9]+ //' 
File1_11_9_1_E.sql 
File2_11_9_1_E.sql 
File3_11_9_1_C.sql 
FILE4_11_9_1_P.sql
FILE5_11_9_1_A.sql 
FILE7_PKG_C.sql 
FILE8_PKG_CV.sql 
FILE10_11_9_1_C.sql 
FILE11_11_9_1_P.sql 
FILE12_11-9-1-P.sql 
FILE13_11-9-1-P.sql 
FILE14_11_9_1_P.sql 
FILE15_11_9_1_P.sql 
FILE16_11_9_1_P.sql 
FILE17_11_9_1_U.sql 
FILE17_11_9_1_U.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ls -1 | sort -t _ -k1.5,1n` this sort on the 5th character forward.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your filenames don't begin with numbers, here's one way using `GNU awk`. It will sort by the first number preceding an underscore, then by order of occurrence. Also generally speaking, parsing `ls` is [a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), although it would 'work' with your filenames. I prefer using `GNU find`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk <(find ./* -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.sql" -printf "%f\n")
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[^0-9]+"
}

{
    a[$2] = (a[$2] ? a[$2] ORS : "") $0
}

END {
    for (i in a) {
        b[j++]=i+0
    }

    n = asort(b)

    for (k=1;k<=n;k++) {
        print a[b[k]]
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Fi1_11_9_1_E.sql 
File2_11_9_1_E.sql 
File3_11_9_1_C.sql 
FILE4_11_9_1_P.sql 
FILE5_11_9_1_A.sql 
FILE7_PKG_C.sql 
FILE8_PKG_CV.sql 
FILE10_11_9_1_C.sql 
FILE11_11_9_1_P.sql 
LE12_11-9-1-P.sql 
FILE13_11-9-1-P.sql 
FILE14_11_9_1_P.sql 
E15_11_9_1_P.sql 
FILE16_11_9_1_P.sql 
FILE17_11_9_1_U.sql 
FILE17_11_9_1_U.sql
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -F "[^0-9]+" '{ a[$2] = (a[$2] ? a[$2] ORS : "") $0 } END { for (i in a) b[j++]=i+0; n = asort(b); for (k=1;k<=n;k++) print a[b[k]] }' <(find ./* -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.sql" -printf "%f\n")
```